# Advanced Popups in R Shiny Leaflet

Tags: r, list, dictionary, leaflet

I have a dataset as follows

```
itemcat country item Price date_today lat lng
Clothes Bangkok Shoes $5 2016-04-27 13.75 100.51 
Clothes Bangkok Tshirt $5 2016-04-27 13.75 100.51 
Clothes Bangkok Skirt $5 2016-04-27 13.75 100.51 
Clothes Bangkok Pants $5 2016-04-27 13.75 100.51
Food    Bangkok Chicken $2 2016-04-27 13.75 100.51
Food    Bangkok Milk   $2  2016-04-27 13.75 100.51
Clothes New York Shoes $5 2016-04-27 40.74 -73.98 
Clothes New York Tshirt $5 2016-04-27 40.74 -73.98 
Clothes New York Skirt $5 2016-04-27 40.74 -73.98 
Clothes New York Pants $5 2016-04-27 40.74 -73.98
```

I have a shiny app that allows the user to pick an itemcat, pick a date, and leaflet will indicate the countries with price information available on the world map.

I want to create popups such that the pop ups are able to display the city and all the items and their prices when clicked on, e.g.:
**City:** Bangkok, **Shoes**:$5, **Tshirt**:$5, **Skirt**:$5, **Pants**:$5

But right now, I'm having trouble displaying these popups with my code. In particular, I don't know how to display multiple variable columns of ITEMS in the popups. The word "city:" pops up, but that is all.

```
####USER INTERFACE####
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("World Cost of Living",
sidebarLayout(position="right",
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("witem", "Select item of comparison", choices = c("Clothes", "Communication", "Income", "Outside Food", "Prepared Food", "Property Price", "Recreation", "Rent", "Transport", "Utilities")),
dateRangeInput("wdaterange", "Select Date Range", start = min(col$date_today), end = max(col$date_today), format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0, language = "en", separator = " to "),
dateInput("wdate", "Select Date", min = min(col$date_today), format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0, language = "en")),

 mainPanel(leafletOutput('map'))
))
)
)
)



####SERVER####

server <- function(input, output, session){

  pal <- colorQuantile("Blues", NULL, n = 5)
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  prices<-col[col$itemcat==input$witem & col$date_today==input$wdate[1],]

  leaflet(prices) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircles(lng = ~lng, lat=~lat, stroke=TRUE, color = "black", weight=1, opacity = 0.2, fill = TRUE, fillColor = ~pal(infl), fillOpacity = 0.2 , radius = ~infl*30)
  })

  #~htmlEscape(country[lng==lng & lat==lat])

  # Show a popup at the given location
  showPopup <- function(itemcat, lat, lng, date) {
    selectedItem <- col[col$itemcat == itemcat & col$lat==lat & col$lng==lng & col$date_today==date,]
    content <- as.character(tagList(
      tags$strong("City:", selectedItem$country),
      tags$strong(HTML(sprintf("%s, %s",
                               selectedItem$item, selectedItem$spore
      )))
    ))
    leafletProxy("map") %>% addPopups(lng, lat, content, layerId = itemcat)
  }

  observe({
    leafletProxy("map") %>% clearPopups()
    event <- input$map_shape_click
    if (is.null(event))
      return()

    isolate({
      showPopup(event$id, event$lat, event$lng, event$date)
    })
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is out-of-date for you but I had the same problem and founs no answer, so if anyone encounters the same problem in the future, he might find an answer here.

The easiest way to show a popup when clicking on a marker is to pass the `popup` option when defining the marker. Example: (server.R)

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  pal <- colorQuantile("Blues", NULL, n = 5)

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  prices<-col[col$itemcat==input$witem & col$date_today==input$wdate[1],]
  leaflet(prices) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircles(lng = ~lng, lat=~lat, fillColor = ~pal(infl),
             popup = "Hello world!")
  })
}
```

I intentionally removed many options in `addCircles` to make it easier to read. This code displays a popup with text `Hello world!` when clicking on the marker. Ok the first step is done. Now let's display the data:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  pal <- colorQuantile("Blues", NULL, n = 5)

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  prices<-col[col$itemcat==input$witem & col$date_today==input$wdate[1],]
  leaflet(prices) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircles(lng = ~lng, lat=~lat, fillColor = ~pal(infl),
             popup = as.character(tagList(
               sprintf("Itemcat: %s", prices$itemcat), tags$br(),
               sprintf("Date: %s", prices$date_today)
  )))
  })
}
```

Now the popup displays the item category and the date.
Note that this code might need editing since I adapted on the fly mine (on whole different dataset, and I use `addCircleMarkers` instead of `addCircles`) but I think it's pretty close to an acceptable solution.

PS it seems that you can also use:

```
popup = paste("Itemcat: ", prices$itemcat, "<br>",
              "Date: ", prices$date_today,"<br>")
```